# Ubuntu boots from USB, error message when trying DVD

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, usb, dvd

I had to setup a couple of PCs recently. When I tried to boot Ubuntu DVD ( burned ISO through 18.04 ), shows an error as given below

[image]

It doesn't even go into the live session. But when I use Rufus in Windows 10 and make a bootable USB, everything is fine. I can use the live session and install Ubuntu as well.

What is wrong ? Now my USB is stuck with Ubuntu. If there is any fix for using through DVD, please share.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an attempt to pxe boot (boot via network).
The last line indicates your system moving on the next boot option on the list as configured at the BIOS menu.

Usually, when nothing is written or "no media found" message shows up - it means that either other boot options are not enabled when booting, no devices currently connected, or the media itself is damaged / contains an unbootable image (usually because it was not burnt correctly).

I suggest checking your BIOS boot order, or trying to manually boot override from the menu directly to the media.
If the media is on the list but booting is not successful, it might need to be burnt again.

Comment: Thanks. But I can see the contents is DVD when used inside another 18.04. I have the same issue with a Windows PE disc. Is it because you need UEFI ?

Comment: Default ubuntu downloads of server and desktop both contain ISOlinux (the set of tools that allow install from a cd/dvd media), and include both UEFI and legacy BIOS boot.

Comment: What could be the issue then ? I got it Ubuntu site yesterday. I will try burning through windows 10 and see. Thanks

Comment: When booting via cd/dvd, make sure your media is bootable (burning the Iso file itself won't do). Either by extracting all contents of the ISO file and writing it all to disk, or by using a 3rd party app such as Nero for Windows or brasero for ubuntu.

Comment: I used Brasero to burn the ISO I got from You Ubuntu. Thanks.